# PHP class design choice

Tags: php, oop

I have a class, to generate a nested unordered html-list.

```
class cTree {    

function cTree(){
}

public function getTree($id = NULL ){
}

private function addSubNode($iParentId, $iLevel){
}
```

Where addSubnode is a recursive function to get the nesting right.

Now, I want to have two navigation menu's on my website. Both unordered lists, but with different markup.

As I see it, there are 3 options:

1. Pass an extra variable to getTree() and addSubNode(), and then use if/else constructions. I don't like that as its not maintainable.
2. add two extra functions to the class, so I'll have e.g. getTopTree()/ getFooterTree and addTopSubNode()/ addFooterSubNode();
3. create two new classes (class cTopMenu extends cTree / class cFooterMenu extends cTree ) and edit getTree/ addSubNode to my liking.

As said, I don't like the 1st option but am not sure about the 2nd and 3rd. What would be the best design choice?

Extra example, to make the situation more clear. It's not the same as above, but definitely comparable. I have a tree for navigating:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="/x">Item 1 </a></li>
  <li><a href="/x">Item 2 </a></li>
  <li><a href="/x">Item 3 </a></li>
</ul>
```

Then I have another one, with administrative options:

```
<form method="post">
 <ul>
   <li>
       <input type="text" value="Item 1" />
       <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="visible_1" name="visible[]"> 
       <label for="visible_1">&nbsp;visible</label>           
   </li>
   <li>
       <input type="text" value="Item 2" />
       <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="visible_2" name="visible[]"> 
       <label for="visible_2">&nbsp;visible</label>           
   </li>
   <li>
       <input type="text" value="Item 3" />
       <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="visible_3" name="visible[]"> 
       <label for="visible_3">&nbsp;visible</label>           
   </li>
 </ul>
</form>
```

Basically its the same tree. For now I extended the basic tree-class, replacing the getTree() and addSubNode() functions.

Comment: How does the markup differ?  Is it the css that differs or the html?  If it is only the styling, add another parameter that allows you to add either an `id` or a `class` to the `ul`.

Comment: Wait a minute! It's a class so just instantiate two different menu objects surely?

Comment: Reinventing the wheel, are we? [look into the `DOMDocument`](http://www.php.net/DOMDocument) and [the `DOMDocumentFragment`](http://www.php.net/DOMDocumentFragment) classes, you're free to extend them if you want, so really you have 4 options

Comment: It's more then styling, e.g. the topmenu has list items with either an a-element or text and an ul, and inside the ul some code to support a generic javascript. The footer menu does not need that extra code.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem, I'll take a look. The code is a few years old and not invented by me :-)

Comment: And maybe the fifth option: use this class like a controller with its views - the controller only create a nested arrays or whatever You tend to use and call the appropriate view once in header or footer menu...

Answer (score 0):

It would be really helpful if you could tell us what are the two expected markups in order to suggest an approach. Having said that I can try a partial answer:

- As you said, the first option does not seem like a good way to go as this puts the responsibility of deciding what to do on the client (i.e. the if/then/else part). This leads to repeating that statement in many places, which causes testing and maintainability problems.
- The problem I see with the second approach is that if you do that, an instance of cTree won't be representing a tree, but some sort of tree collection of functions. As a result you would be using some OO constructions but you won't be adhering to the OO paradigm. Also, consider that if you later decide to have a new type of tree (e.g. sidebar tree) you should add new set of functions (`getSideTree()`/`addSideSubNode()`), which also doesn't scale.

The question IMHO is if you should treat this case by creating a specific subclass for each case or if they are just two `cTree` instances that collaborate with another object to get the desired output. As I said before, it is hard to tell without knowing the two expected outputs.

**Edit**
Based on the new information, I guess that both approaches (subclassing or compostiion) are valid:

- Subclassing. I would have an abstract class (`cTree`) that does everything except for rendering the node. The method for doing this would be abstract and the concrete subclasses (`topTree` and `footerTree`) would be in charge of handling this. You may want to look at the template [method pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/template-method-pattern.html).
- Composition. Here you would only have one tree class that is in charge of rendering the tree structure and that delegates the node rendering to another object. That other object would be modeled in a separate hierarchy (e.g. abstract class `treeNode` with `topNode` and `footerNode`). I like this because it clearly states that what is different between trees is not their structure, but the nodes.

As you can see the second option is converting an overridden method implementation in subclasses into a hierarchy of polymorphic objects. Which option to use depends on the complexity of the rendering process and in personal tastes.

HTH

Comment: Thanks, that helped. Give me a minute, I'll give a better example in the start post.